# Indy adds = at every 72nd char with Multi part form data Post

Tags: delphi, post, delphi-xe, indy, multipartform-data

With Delphi XE and Indy, I got some code which submits to a web form.

```
idhttp := TidHttp.create;
postData := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
try
    postData.AddFormField('name', edName.text);
    postData.AddFormField('email', edEmail.txt);
    postData.AddFormField('description', mDescription.text);

    idhttp.Request.ContentType := 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' + postData.Boundary;
    idhttp.fHttp.Post('http://www.example.com/contact.php', postData);

    ShowMessage('Thank you for your contact us.');
finally
    postData.Free;
    idHttp.Free;
end;
```

However, when I enter something likes this in the description memo.

```
This is a really long descriptie piece of text so we can see just how it's wrapping these lines and what it's doig to them I think it's making a hash of it.

Argh waht a pain.
```

I get

```
This is a really long descriptie piece of text so we can see just how =
it's wrapping these lines and what it's doig to them I think it's maki=
ng a hash of it.

Argh waht a pain.
```

So it seems to be word wrapping for me, with =
Anyone with any clues?

Comment: Yes my english is a bit off... it's very late here and just a bit tired. I kept the typos to show that it does get split there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you see is correct behavior.  The `TIdFormDataField.ContentTransfer` property defaults to `quoted-printable` for text fields.  That is exactly the type of encoding you are seeing being generated.  In `quoted-printable`, a sole `=` character followed by a line break is called a "soft" break.  It is how MIME breaks up long lines of text to fit within line length restrictions in various protocols, such as email.

You can change the `ContentTransfer` property to any of the following supported values:

- a blank string
- `7bit`
- `8bit`
- `binary`
- `quoted-printable`
- `base64`

If you do not want your text to be encoded, then set the `ContentTransfer` property to any of the values other than `quoted-printable` or `base64`.

Comment: Thanks, I saw you answer like this to a similar question. And like the other user I am using the Indy version which came with DelphiXE - which means it doesn't support changing this, so I have to get the new version which is a bit of a pain. So I has hoping for some other magic solution...

Comment: If the shipped version of Indy does not do what you need, and you don't want to install a newer version (which you should do), then you will have to avoid `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` and encode your own MIME data manually in a `TMemoryStream` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It encodes the stuff as quoted-printable. You need to decode it before displaying it.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be the issue. Is there a way to change that, without updating Indy. I don't need utf-8 support for this

Comment: I think the sane way to go is to accept that there will be some sort of encoding, and decode it.

Comment: Other sources of data such as web forms all submit here without issue, so don't want to add extra handling in there just because delphi/indy wants to be different.

Comment: Indy is not being different.  What it is doing is standard MIME handling, per the MIME RFCs.